# Automatic adjustment of UILabel height according to content

Tags: ios, uilabel, xcode9.1

I'm using Xcode 9.1
I want a simple thing. I want to have a UILabel that adjust its size to show its content.

For that, I'm doing the next things.
First, I add 3 constraints.
1.- Center it horizontally.
2.- Fix it a distance 10 from the left margin.
3.- Fix it a distance 20 from the top margin.

I put number of Lines = 0
And in Line Break : Word Wrap

Now I modify the text from "Label" to a large one. However, only the first line is shown. What I am doing wrong?

PD: I'm a noob, so at the moment, I just want to use the utilities pane. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running the code ? Is the label not growing in simulator or you looking at interface builder

Comment: @Luciano Falco try giving height constraint and make it >=.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Wow, when I run the code the label adjusts its height. Is there a way to show this in the interface builder? Why it doesnt show this?